# JQM + iScroll 4 scroll wierd scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, iscroll4

I'm trying to use JQM and iScroll 4 for a project and convert it to a native app with xCode.
I like to use iScroll because the header and footer must always be displayed.
The problem is, the scrolling part isn't working, it creates the 'scrolling-div', but when I try to scroll in it, it just bounce back to the top.

Here is my HTML and JS

A simple HTML page:

```
<div data-role="page" class="pages" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#"class="showMenu menuBtn" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
        <h1>header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="slide-content">
                <h3>Slide Menu</h3>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li><a href="#home">Scroll naar benenden
                        </a></li>
                            ... lots of <li>
                            <li><a href="#home">Scroll naar benenden
                        </a></li>
             </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>footer</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myScroll
function loaded() {
    myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
```

If you need more info, ask and you will receive :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use overthrow, albeit still experimental. It's being developed by Filament/JQM, so I guess this will be the way to go since scrollview will not be supported any longer.

See here:  http://filamentgroup.com/lab/overthrow/

and here:  http://filamentgroup.github.com/Overthrow/

Comment: um. Have not really tried it. Just found overthrow a few days ago. but from what they say it should be a cross platform solution

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at jqm version 1.1 (should be released very soon), it has a persistent header and footer you can look at the rc1 docs here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html

Comment: Allright, nice, maybe I will use this in the future. But for the moment, I'll go with the solution from @frequent

Comment: I also tried this, in the browser, no problem, but when I go native, it want slide when i tough the content. to bad :(

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can easily be solved. The problem is that iScroll can't determine the height of your scrolling div. The potential causes are:

- incorrect css
- loading of the content takes isn't complete when DOMContentLoaded is fired.